# Streaming TCP data to a Client with Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have read several different SO posts on using python as a TCP client and am not able to connect to a server sending data via TCP at 1hz which is hosted locally.  The connection parameters I am using are:

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip=socket.gethostbyname("127.0.0.1")
port=1234
address=(ip,port)
client.connect(address)
while True:
    print("test1")
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print("test2")
    print(data)
```

I believe that it is failing on the second line of the while statement but do not know why because it hangs and I am not given an error.  Below are links to the SO articles, I have read and I have attached a screenshot from a TCP client tool that I am able to connect to the data server with.  I'm expecting the data to stream in my print statement, is this not how it works? Whats the best way to make a persistent connection to a TCP connection with python?

Researched:
[(Very) basic Python client socket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749341/very-basic-python-client-socket-example),[Python continuous TCP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792834/python-continuous-tcp-connection),[Python stream data over TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102775/python-stream-data-over-tcp)

[image]

Comment: Your client program is not connecting to the server in the first place, i.e. you are missing a `client.connect(address)`. And without connecting you cannot receive data.

Comment: missed that line in my copy and paste...Connection parameter should have been in the OP

Comment: Your client works almost perfectly when I run it. Perhaps the problem is with your server? Try testing your client against another server. I used netcat. In one window run `nc -l 1234`. In another window run your client. By "almost perfectly," I mean that it entered an infinite loop after the connection closed. If `recv` ever returns `''`, you should exit the loop.

Comment: I think you are correct that my server is the problem I just rebooted my machine and it works, I need to find out what is happening/wrong with the ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with sockets: In order to communicate over a socket, you have to open a connection to an existing socket (a "client"), or create an open socket that waits for a connection (a "server"). In your code, you haven't done either, so `recv()` is waiting for data that will never arrive.

The simple case is connecting as a client to a server which is waiting/listening for connections. In your case, assuming that there is a server on your machine listening on port 1234, you simply need to add a `connect()` call.

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip=socket.gethostbyname("127.0.0.1")
port=1234
address=(ip,port)
client.connect(address)  ## <--Add this line.
while True:
    print("test1")
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print("test2")
    print(data)
```

Comment: sorry had that line in my code missed copying it when I posted the original question.

Comment: Is the "sending" port already open, ready to send the text you want to print? If not, then I'll augment my answer to describe how a server needs to be implemented.